# Send Microsoft teams meeting invite using springboot

Tags: spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am working on a web-app which requires triggering a Teams meeting invite through Springboot api. How to do that? The article I found in Microsoft [official website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is not very clear. They are talking about some permissions and a HTTP request to the end point
`POST /me/onlineMeetings`
but what it the host for this endpoint? What is Graph API? Any reference to some detailed documentation would be very helpful.

Comment: If you check the documentation they even have samples on how to make a request. So I suggest to read past the first 5 lines and read the full documentation.